# Given a list of linear equations, what is a neat way to use solve on the equations of this list?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

Suppose I have a list of equations, say `{2x+b+3c=3, 7x+2b+c=1, x+b+9c=-2}` what is a neat way to use `Solve[]` on that list? Because `Solve[]`'s syntax is:

```
Solve[a x + y == 7 && b x - y == 1, {x, y}]
```

I know I could transform it to a string and replace the `,` with `&&`, erase `{}` and convert to expression to use there. But I suspect there might be some nicer way to do it.

Comment: `Solve[{2 x + b + 3 c == 3, 7 x + 2 b + c == 1, x + b + 9 c == -2}, {x,
   b, c}]` would also be valid syntax. So your only problem would be to replace `=` (`Set`) by `==` (`Equal`).

Comment: If the number of unknowns is the same as the number of equations you can just use Solve[list]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this way?

```
expression = Hold[{2 x + b + 3 c = 3, 7 x + 2 b + c = 1, x + b + 9 c = -2}];
Solve[
 ReleaseHold[expression /. Set -> Equal],
 {x, b, c}
 ]
```

> {{x -> -(55/13), b -> 209/13, c -> -(20/13)}}

`Hold` around the list of "equations" is necessary to prevent *Mathematica* from evaluating it (and throwing errors).

Answer (score 4):

I will assume that your use of `Set` (`=`) instead of `Equal` (`==`) to define your equations was just a typo, since you correctly used `==` in your syntax example.

```
listeq = {2 x + b + 3 c == 3, 7 x + 2 b + c == 1, x + b + 9 c == -2};
```

However, you may not know that Solve will also take lists of equations as input, in addition to equations linked with logical `And` (`&&`). Additionally, when you have as many equations as you have variables, you can even skip the variable list. So the shortest approach would be:

```
Solve[listeq]

(* Out: {{b -> 209/13, c -> -(20/13), x -> -(55/13)}} *)
```

If you want to turn your list of equations into an `And` expression (`&&`), you can do that too pretty easily:

```
And @@ listeq

(* Out: b + 3 c + 2 x == 3 && 2 b + c + 7 x == 1 && b + 9 c + x == -2 *)
```

So you could also write `Solve[And @@ listeq]` and obtain the same result as before.